# How to retrieve records from Hibernate having many to many relationship?

Tags: hibernate

I have three tables

```
Users                           Deal                Dealusers
==========                     ======               ==========
userid(PK)                     dealid(PK)           dealid(PK+FK)
                                                    userid(PK+FK)
```

Now i have generate mapping using hibernate tool in eclipse
so i got POJO class & hbm file for the Users & Deal table only due to this many to many relationship.

Now i want to query "get list of users who purchased dealid=1"

So how should i query this using hibernate?
Thanks in advance.

```
<set name="userses" table="dealusers" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="dealid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="com.test.model.Users">
                <column name="userid" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Deal deal = session.get(Deal.class, 1);
return deal.getUsers();
```

As simple as that.

Comment: Sorry but i dont have User object in generated hbm file instead of that it contains
private Set<Users> userses = new HashSet<Users>(0);

Comment: The above set of users is precicely the set that you want to return.

Comment: Yes but its lazy loading so how should i intialize it

Comment: `Hibernate.initialize(deal.getUsers()); return deal.getUsers();`